# xml autocomplete fails

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, adt

I use eclipse Galileo 3.6 it worked fine till yesterday when I updated ADT to the version 12. Now, when I try to use the quick code autocomplete (that's using Ctr+spacebar) such as "fill_parent" instead of "match_parent" or whatever else the new code inserts but erase a great part of the following line code.

I tried to reinstall ADT and Eclipse but it's the same.

Incredible it works fine inside Motordev but I'm not used to work with it.

Can someone have idea to solve this problem or how, I successfully can remove ADT so I download the old one? I tried to uninstall from the help software but it is still there.

Thank you

Comment: I updated Motodev to the new version and get the same problem but after many tests I found a workaround to solve the problem.

Comment: can you share your workaround?

Comment: Yes, it's easy. step first the problem happen only in XML not in java class....so 1) open your layout or other xml  2)click where you want to write the code and write the first letter 3) ctrl+space to open the autocomplete suggestion panel 4) make your choice and double click it 5) it is set in place correctly...repeat all time steps 2-5. It works fine in my system and once you get the habit it's fast the same.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late but maybe it will help someone else. The autocomplete seems to only have this issue if you haven't entered your quote marks yet. So instead of hitting autocomplete here:

```
android:layout_width=
```

hit it here instead:

```
android:layout_width="
```